# How to change ListViewItem Background while selecting Items of a ListView using keyboard UP & Down button

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have ListView with following style for IsMouseOver

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" ></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But when I select the Items using Keyboard UP & DOWN keys is shows default Blue background. I want the background to exactly like the IsMouseOver style.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
 <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" ></Setter>
        </Trigger>
```